# How can I add my printer( Epson M100) that is not on the printers list on the system dialog? Its linux drivers in Epson site is also gone (404)

Tags: printer

I cannot connect my printer correctly. It is Epson Workforce M100, bought several years ago. It can connect to the modem with a data cable and can be discovered by my system(5.1.7), and it is seen in the printers list. I can pick it but in the next page, where the list of printers are shown, M100 is not listed so I cannot choose a printer.[image]

I tried to pick a random one but then it just prints out nonsense characters. Also on the Epson site, driver links for M100 are going nowhere and I get a 404. I searched for the missing files but I couldn't find them elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Zey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the driver download site is now up and running (or maybe you were on some other site?). https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult shows quite a few downloads available for your model:

[image]

Clicking the download button for the first one, and after accepting Epson's Software License Agreement, I can see a list of available packages:
[image]

Download [epson-inkjet-printer-201215w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/f/01/00/02/09/08/f14ac48ce7e19d8c077153dfe9f496cf0b2a1486/epson-inkjet-printer-201215w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb) and install it using dpkg or [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/).

```
wget http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/f/01/00/02/09/08/f14ac48ce7e19d8c077153dfe9f496cf0b2a1486/epson-inkjet-printer-201215w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-201215w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```

Your printer's model should be now present in the add new printer dialog:

[image]

Let us know how this works out for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I went to the address you gave in your answer again to check if it got fixed after me, but it still shown as 404 to me. Why would it be? How can I obtain that epson-inkjet-printer-201215w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb file? Thank you.

Comment: I made it! Thank you! Appearently my blockers was blocking something, after opening the page without add-ons I managed to get the file! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yeah, looking back now, the link was not using SSL, maybe that is why it was blocked. Nevertheless, added a direct download link for that file in the answer.